# Delete Records Based on Query Output

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, `THEKITCHEN` with a query:

```
SELECT FOOD, COUNT(FOOD) 
FROM THEKITCHEN 
GROUP BY FOOD
```

This returns an output of:

```
FOIEGRAS    1
APPLEPIE    1
SORBET      1
FILETMIGNON 1
BRANZINO    5
TRUFFLES    2
ESCARGO     1
POULET      2
```

And what I do next is delete items using the following:

```
DELETE FROM THEKITCHEN 
WHERE FOOD IN ('FOIEGRAS')
```

Now this works but sometimes I need to delete all items/records in that column. And running that `DELETE` statement 15-40 times becomes annoying.

Is it possible to get the output of the initial query into a variable and then use the `DELETE` statement on that variable to delete all the items? I've tried

```
UPDATE THEKITCHEN 
SET FOOD = NULL;
```

But that errored in that my table doesn't allow Null.

Thanks!

---

Update: THEKITCHEN has other columns which I do not want to delete records from. So TRUNCATE TABLE THEKITCHEN would lose a lot of important stuff.

---

Update: Yes TRUNCATE TABLE THEKITCHEN is the way to go!

Comment: If you want to delete *all* the items, regardless of what they are, a simple `DELETE THEKITCHEN` or `TRUNCATE TABLE THEKITCHEN` would suffice, no need to query for them first. If you simply want to delete *more than one* item, you can do `WHERE FOOD IN ('FOIEGRAS', 'APPLEPIE', 'SORBET')`. If you want to delete based on a *specific query*, use `DELETE ... FROM` or a CTE (`WITH BADKITCHEN AS (SELECT ... FROM THEKITCHEN) DELETE BADKITCHEN`), but specific scenario is not in your question.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing since you refer to deleting a *column* - you delete *rows*.

Comment: True.. thank you for pointing that out. I meant all the rows in a column. @Stu

Comment: @vicscul no, you mean all the rows in the *table*

Comment: A table consists of rows (the vertical things) and each of those rows contains columns (the horizontal things). You can only delete rows; columns cannot be individually deleted. You can *drop* columns from a table, but then it will disappear from all rows. You can set columns to `NULL` (as you've done), but if the column does not allow `NULL`, that won't work. I suggest you carefully reconsider what it really is you're after -- describe it with a before-and-after of your table if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all the food items, you don't need a condition at all, just use `delete from thekitchen`. Moreover, you can use a DDL statement `truncate table thekitchen` which would be much faster.

Comment: After much reading and understanding what the DELETE statement does, yes TRUNCATE TABLE THEKITCHEN is the route to go